# Can i plug a usb keyboard to my iphone while it's connected to my mac?

Tags: iphone, backup, password, data-recovery

I need to backup my iphone 5s but the screen is completely broken, it's all black and the touchscreen doesn't work so i need a way to control my phone from a keyboard to back it up from icloud that recognises it.

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Please don't ask the practically same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

Not a USB keyboard afaik, but this [lightning keyboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UTUDK26) has been reported to work with iPhones.

There's a thread on the [apple discussion board](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8067615) by someone in the same situation as you that used the keyboard linked above as part of their backup process.

Comment: thanks but the home key is also broken :(

Comment: i've ordered a lightning keyboard, let's hope it works